# Adding Facebook Online Account - "application you are trying to use doesn't exist or has been disabled"

Tags: facebook, online-accounts

I noticed on April 9 that Empathy wasn't connecting to Facebook Chat, so I opened Online Accounts, and it appears that I needed to authorize Ubuntu to access Facebook.  But then I couldn't do that - when I try, the web server at Facebook responds with

"Facebook
Error Accessing App
We're sorry, but the application you're trying to use doesn't exist or has been disabled."

I tried removing and adding the Facebook account again, and got the same result.

Does anyone know if Facebook shut down the authentication app due to the Heartbleed bug?  If so, any word on when it will be back up again?

Comment: What ubuntu version are you on?

Comment: 13.10.  All software has been updated.

Comment: I with the same problem.

Comment: Same really kinda annoying cause I use my other messenger accounts far less.

Comment: This bug is known and beeing fixed: See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/account-plugins/+bug/1304798

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same problem. There is an update released for empathy which fixes this. Software Updater should do it, or check out some launchpad ppa for empathy

Comment: Now fixed in Ubuntu 14.04.